# Java Picture copy method

Tags: java

I have been working on this method in Picture.java for a programming course. The code is supposed to take an original image with a target image, x and y coordinates, and return a merged image with the original image pasted on these coordinates on the target image. A precondition is that the target image must have bigger dimensions than the original image. Here's the code I wrote:

```java
public Picture copyPicture (Picture target, int startx, int starty)
    {
      Picture merged = new Picture(target);
      for (int x = 0, mergx = startx; x < getWidth(); x++, mergx++)
      {
        for (int y = 0, mergy = starty; y < getHeight(); y++, mergy++)
        {
          Pixel orig = getPixel(x,y);
          Pixel mergedPix = merged.getPixel(mergx, mergy);
          mergedPix.setColor(orig.getColor());
        }
      }
      return merged;
    }
```

However, the method doesn't seem to work for me. I'm not sure what I did wrong, but nothing happens to either of the images. Can someone give me a tip?

Comment: Could you provide more code from your class?

Comment: @AlexeyUsharovski sure, what kind of example would you like to see?

Comment: @jay'sotherotherclone Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.